# javascript array shifting one object into front

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have an array

```
const cityList = [
 {id: 1, name: 'Dallas'},
 {id: 2, name: 'Houston'},
 {id: 3, name: 'San Antonio'},
 {id: 4, name: 'Austin'},
]
```

I want to select the Houston that object and move to the top of the array.

I came up with

```
cityList.forEach(city => {
  if(city.name === 'Houston') {
    cityList.splice(...);   // then do a unshift() to top here...
  }
});
```

but I am not sure this is the most efficient way to do cuz I want to cut the whole object and move to the top.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply move one object from one position to another position using `[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const cityList = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Dallas'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Houston'},
  {id: 3, name: 'San Antonio'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Austin'},
];

const index = cityList.findIndex(({ name }) => name === 'Houston');
if (index >= 0) {
  cityList.splice(0, 0, cityList.splice(index, 1)[0]);
}
console.log(cityList);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `.forEach()` to iterate, or `.splice()` for the removal.

Instead, I'd use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the object, and then [`.copyWithin()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin) to shift the elements over before putting the targeted object at the first index.

```js
const cityList = [
 {id: 1, name: 'Dallas'},
 {id: 2, name: 'Houston'},
 {id: 3, name: 'San Antonio'},
 {id: 4, name: 'Austin'},
];

function cityToFront(city) {
  const idx = cityList.findIndex(o => o.name === city);
  if (idx === -1) return;
  
  const obj = cityList[idx];      // grab the object
  cityList.copyWithin(1, 0, idx); // shift others over one index
  cityList[0] = obj;              // assign the object to the start
  
  // You can do this in one line with destructuring assignment
  // [cityList[0], ] = [cityList[idx], cityList.copyWithin(1, 0, idx)];
  
  // It evaluates and holds the value of cityList[idx] before
  // doing the copyWithin()
}

cityToFront("Houston");

console.log(cityList);
```

This lets you accomplish the gory details using lower level implementations, and it does so without allocating any temporary arrays.

Comment: You know, I've been doing JS for over twenty years, and I don't know that I've ever before seen a use for `copyWithin`.  Of course, as my own answer shows, I prefer not to mutate input data.  But if you're going to do so, this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write code that does not mutate the input data, returning appropriate copies as necessary.  I also prefer solving problems like this slightly more abstractly.  Here is a function which does both, using `.slice` instead of `.splice` and accepting an arbitrary predicate to match:

```js
const moveToFront = (pred = () => false) =>  (xs = [], index = xs .findIndex (pred)) => 
  index > -1 
    ? [xs [index], ... xs .slice (0, index), ...xs .slice (index)]
    : [...xs]


const cityList = [{id: 1, name: 'Dallas'}, {id: 2, name: 'Houston'}, {id: 3, name: 'San Antonio'}, {id: 4, name: 'Austin'}]

console .log (moveToFront (({name}) => name == 'Houston') (cityList))
```

If we now want something which takes a city name and a list of cities, we can partially apply the above version like this:

```js
const moveCityToFront = (name) => 
  moveToFront (({name: n}) => name == n)

moveCityToFront ('Houston') (cityList)
//=> [{id: 2, name: 'Houston}, {id: 1, name: 'Dallas'}, ...]
```